# Using static var and instance var as the same name in Swift Protocol

Tags: swift

using static var and instance var as the variable same name in Swift that will occur compiler error. why?

```
example:
protocol naming {
   static var firstName: String { get }
   var firstName: String { get }
}

class Employee: NSObject, naming {

   class var firstName: String {
       return "MyName"
   }
   var firstName: String {
      return Employee.firstName
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. (One of several connected with static variables in protocols.) And in Swift 2.0, it's fixed.